# Why does instanceof return false on Chrome, Safari and Edge and true on FireFox?

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, dom-events

I'm using CKEditor to upload some files by dragging them onto the editor.

I'm seeing this weird behavior in the drop event. When inspecting the event object, I can get to the `files` property. The debugger shows this as having type `FileList`. However, when I do `files instanceof FileList` I get `false` in Chrome, Safari and Edge and `true` in FireFox (see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dq3xyo5/3/)).

What is going on here?

It seems that it must have something to do with how CKEditor routes events because without CKEditor it seems like it does work. Here's a [basic file drag-drop jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nu1besp/) I forked so that it prints `instanceof FileList`.

I'm working around it now by doing `Object.prototype.toString.call(files) == "[object FileList]"`. But that doesn't seem like a good long term solution.

Edit: I've posted [a bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=716423) on Chromium as I feel this is something in Chrome that's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responses to the bug report contained the answer to this question.

By [rbyers](https://bugs.chromium.org/u/rbyers@chromium.org/):

> This isn't just about the FileList but the entire DragEvent.  Debugging this I found that CKEditor is creating an iframe, and so the event types delivered to the iframe have different prototype objects than the main window where the event handler is running.  Breaking on the 'drop' event listener (before any of the JS runs and potentially mucks with the event):
>
> `Object.getPrototypeOf(c)===window.DragEvent.prototype`
> `false`
>
> `Object.getPrototypeOf(c)===document.querySelector('iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contentWindow.DragEvent.prototype`
> `true`
>
> See the documentation of instanceof and multiple contexts here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_context_(e.g._frames_or_windows)
>
> However, I indeed see that instance of returns true for such cases in Firefox. Here's a really simple reproduction: http://jsbin.com/yefesuv

If you read more responses, it turns out there was a discrepancy between the Web IDL and ES spec where FireFox was following Web IDL and all the other browsers ES. [They have updated the Web IDL spec](https://github.com/heycam/webidl/pull/356) and there is [a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1360715) for FireFox. It'll be a while before FireFox will change its behaviour due to backwards compatibility.